# ArrayList<HashMap> returning empty in tests and UI?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

Here's my code. I apologize for the sloppiness but essentially what it's supposed to do is simulate the backwards learning algorithm used by switches. The handleInput method takes in the src and dest MAC addresses and a port number and adds the src MAC and port# as a HashMaps into an ArrayList. The whole method is useless right now because none of the HashMaps stay in the ArrayList for some reason. Any help is much appreciated!

```
public class Switching {
    ArrayList<HashMap> switchTable = new ArrayList<HashMap>();

    public String handleInput(String srcMacAddress, int portNumber, String destMacAddress){
        String output = "";
        HashMap tableEntry = new HashMap();
        tableEntry.put(srcMacAddress, portNumber);
        for (HashMap hm : switchTable) {
            if (hm.containsKey(destMacAddress)) {
                 output += hm.get(destMacAddress).toString();
            } else {
                 output += "Ports flooded";
            }
        }
        switchTable.add(tableEntry);
        return output;
    }

    public ArrayList<HashMap> getTable(){
        return switchTable;
    }



public class SwitchingTests {
    @Test
    public void testSwitching(){
        new Switching().handleInput("123456", 12, "abcdef");
        ArrayList<HashMap> switchingTable = new Switching().getTable();
        Assert.assertEquals(switchingTable.toString(), "[{123456=12}]");
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, the very first instruction of the method replaces the switchTable by a new empty one... Also, don't use raw types. It should be a `List<Map<String, Integer>>`.

Comment: Can you add any more code with use of the class, and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a `Switching` object and call `handleInput(...)` on it and then proceed to create a new `Switching` object and get its table.

You need to get the table from the one you already created.

```
public class SwitchingTests {
    @Test
    public void testSwitching(){
        Switching switching = new Switching();
        switching.handleInput("123456", 12, "abcdef");
        ArrayList<HashMap> switchingTable = switching.getTable();
        Assert.assertEquals(switchingTable.toString(), "[{123456=12}]");
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh, Sorry, I was trouble shooting and declared the class variable as null and forgot to change it back. I'm still having the same issue though.

Comment: I see. then we will need to see more code as to how you are using the class as that was the only obvious reason why the `switchTable` would not keep its contents.

Comment: @trcoats I updated the answer with a solution to your real problem.

Answer (score 0):

inside your handleInput method you are creating new switchTable.

 what you have to do is to change your line 

switchTable = new ArrayList() to switchTable = getTable();